# Spring Data JDBC - how to have dynamic db schemas for entities known only at run time?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

I have a database with multiple schemas (one schema per customer), with each schema having the same tables.   This is a common pattern in multitenant apps.

I'm trying to use Spring Data JDBC to access these tables.   I see how you can specify a single schema through properties, or through NamingStrategy, but it looks like these must be set at startup and cannot be changed.

For every crud operation, I need to be able to specify the schema.   Is this possible?